# Alternative for case / switch in c# CS:GO game related

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

Ok guys so I'm making a game based on CS:GO and I stucked on this part of the code.

What I need is an alternitive for the switch 'cause if you look closely I tried to use a varible on the case when I was suposed to use a constant.

I started to learn in C# at my school about 1 month ago but my teacher it's a very hard person to try to communicate with so your basicly my last hope to find a solution for this problem.

And BTW sorry for my english but I'm portuguese and the teaching of English here in Portugal is very bad :(

Anyways thank you for supporting me :)

```
Console.Write("Choose a skin to sell");
ConsoleKeyInfo opg;
int xg = 0, yg = 0;
Console.Clear();
xg = 0;
yg = 0;
bool zg = true;
while (zg) {
    do {
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Clear();
        for (int i = c; i <= c; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("    [ ] - {0}\t{1}", wpn[inv[c]], price[inv[c]]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("    [ ] - EXIT ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(yg, xg);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("    [x]");
        opg = Console.ReadKey();

        if (opg.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow) xg--;
        if (opg.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow) xg++;
        if (xg < 0) xg = 0;
        if (xg > ca) xg = ca;

    }
    while (opg.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    Console.Clear();
    switch (xg) {
        case c:
            break;
        case cb:
            zg = false;
            break;
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Just use `if` instead of `switch`. By the way, are you aware of [SO in Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)? Oh, also, *please* indent your code properly.

Comment: @LeeHarrison The generally accepted brace style for C# is on the next line, like the original question had. Just letting you know for the future and in case someone changes it.

Comment: I know that I guess it was just some mistake of the browser

Answer (score 1):

One way to replace a **switch case - break** is a chain of **if - else if**.

For example your code would be:

```
if (xg == c)
{
    // do something
}
else if (xg == cb) {
    zg = false;
    // do something else
}
else if (xg == anotherVariable) {
    // more stuff
}
```

and so on...

Also, you should always properly indent the code because, even if it's not required in c# (as opposed to other languages like Python), is really important to write readable code.

Comment: I know, I do indent my code properly I guess this was just a reading mistake of the browser. Anyway thaks for your help.